# CSS select only elements that dont have a class starting with this

Tags: css-selectors

Hi,

I have this html code:

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <a href="#">Locations</a>
  <ul class="submenu1">
   <li><a href="https://url.com">London</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://url.com">York</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <ul class="submenu2">
   <li><a href="https://url.com">Site</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://url.com">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I want to select all the a elements EXCEPT the ones that are children to the `submenu` class elements.

I tried like this:

```
ul li a:not([class^="submenu"] a) {background-color:darkkhaki;}
```

but it wont work. Whats the right selector for this case?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello dear CSS friend!

In other words, taking your example, you want to select "Locations" and "About" links but not the others.

### (Kind of) dirty one

The easier to understand solution is to apply styles to all `a` then remove the styles to the others.

```
li > a {
     /* Styles you want to apply */
}

[class^="submenu"] a {
    /* Remove styles here */
}
```

It's always dirty to place styles then remove them, because it's less maintainable and a bit more heavy. But it will do the job.

### Nicer solution

In your case, the submenu links are the only child of your `li` elements. That's why I would try to target the links that are not only child of your list item to style those, like that.

```
li a:not(:only-child) {
    /* Your styles here */
}
```

For more information on :only-child pseudo class, I leave you with some reading :)
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child

Don't hesitate if you have question, and have fun!

Answer (score -1):

**Option 1:**

This will work:

```
ul li a {
  background-color: darkkhaki;
}
ul ul li a {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Just reset the styles on the elements you don't want styled.

**Option 2:**

If you have a container, for example a `<div id="menu">` you can do:

```
#menu > ul > li > a {
  background-color: darkkhaki;
}
```

Comment: That will work but not the solution Im looking for. I need a more direct approach.

Comment: the :not() keyword only supports simple class or tag statements, a "more direct approach" doesn't exist in CSS3.

Comment: And although not related to your question, if I was a maintainer of such code I would sincerely hate whoever wrote something so obscure, even if it was myself 6 months ago. Just unsolicited friendly advice.

Comment: Thank you anyway.

Comment: @DanyAlejandro yes there is a more direct solution, at least one but we could find some others I think. Have a look at the one with `:not()` right here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56951476/4962904 Have a good day :)

Comment: yeah, really depends on your target audience but you would know